# How to create a Java Class while Tomcat startup?

Tags: java, class, tomcat

I have a main Java application running in a tomcat environment. 
Now i have written a java class, put it into a JAR file and in the TCs lib folder. I can access that class now in the main app by importing the class and calling the constructer.

is there a way to create that class once at TCs startup. so i can access the classes variables?

Thanks!
e.

//EDIT 1
here is my example:

Beach.java

```
public class Beach {
    public static void main(String []args) {
      System.out.println("***********************");
     }
}
```

MyAppServletContextListener.java

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyAppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
         System.out.println("**************** ServletContextListener started");
       Beach x = new Beach();

   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
   }
}
```

all this goes into a jar file and into :
…/WEB-INF/lib/beach.jar

and this is my addition to Web.xml:

```
<web-app>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             MyAppServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

and this is the server.log error:

```
10:42:26,440 | ERROR | [[/APP]] | Error configuring application listener of class MyAppServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyAppServletContextListener
```

Comment: Seems you're looking for the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class implementing `ServletContextListener`

Once registered this class will allow you to invoke the desired constructor.

```
public class MyAppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
       YourClass x = new YourClass();
   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
   }
}
```

You need to register this class into the web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.yourpackage.MyAppServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: hi @Nirekin thanks a lot. i am not too familiar with that suff .. as you may notice :) i have updated my doings in the thread ... TC cannot find the source :( thanks!

Comment: in the web.xml you need to add the package to your class 'com.yourpackage.MyAppServletContextListener'